# In your own words: what is JavaFX and Java applet? What are their differences?

Tags: java, javafx, applet

Is [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) the same as [Java applets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet)?

Comment: @Aziz the "In your own words" really gave it away

Comment: no its not a homework..... arhggg I should have used other words
:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the two is the language in which they are written. JavaFX applications are created using the JavaFX Script language and are compiled with a separate compiler that sits atop the Java Development Kit and Java Runtime Environment. You can use JavaFX Script to create Java applets, but applets can of course be written in Java without using JavaFX.

JavaFX Script is specifically geared toward creating rich interfaces and is meant to make it easier to design such applications, while Java on its own is much more broadly focused.

Comment: Source: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091224081418AAUh9pG If you copypaste other's words it would adorn yourself if you provide the source along and put the quote in quote tags instead of doing as if it are your own words.